# Python Executable File closes instantly

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd

I made a program in python 2.7. I set up py2exe and made my program in to an executable file. I can run the .exe file perfectly fine. When I upload it on file hosting sites and people download it they aren't able to run it. The program closes instantly after the user clicks run. How can I fix this? All help is much appreciated.

Here is what my setup file looks like

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe


setup(console=['mole calc.py'])
```

I tried it with import time as well

Here is the beginning of the program

```
from __future__ import division
while True:
    value= raw_input("Welcome, chose the type of function you would like to use : Y = Moles to Particles, X = Particles to Moles, Z = Moles to Mass in Grams, C = Mass in Grams to Moles, V = Moles to Liters, B = Liters to moles ")


    if value in ['y', 'Y']:
            x= input ("Enter value of mole ")
            y=x*6.02*10**23
            print y
```

Comment: There is not enough information to diagnose the problem; we'd need to see the relevant bits of the code at least.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question. Also, nobody here is going to download your executable and run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distribute the entire "dist" directory, not just the exe file.
See http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FAQ (Section: "What are all those files?")

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that I had to include the other files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your file on mediafire, it looks like you did not provide nor explain to end users that they will need the Microsoft Visual C runtime DLL to run.

Re-read step 5 of the py2exe tutorial (http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step5)

Comment: ooga's answer may be a better answer than this, but this has to be addressed as well.